# Excel removes my query connection on it's own and gives me several error messages

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, azure-data-explorer, kql

I know that this is a really long post but I'm not sure of what part of my process is making my file crash, so I tried to detail everything about what I did to get to the error messages.

So, first of all, I created a query on Kusto, which looks something similar to this but in reality is 160 lines of code, this is just a summarized version of what my code might do just to show my working process.

- First, what I do in Session_Id_List is create a list of all distinct Session Id's from the past day.
- Then on treatment_alarms1 I count the amount of alarms for each type of alarm that was active during each session.
- Then, on treatment_alarms2 I create a list which might look something like this

**1x Alarm_Type_Number1**

**30x Alarm_Type_Number2**

**7x Alarm_Type_Number3**

and like that for each treatment, so I have a list of all alarms that were active for that treatment.

Lastly, I create a left outer join with Session_Id_List and treatment_alarms2. This means that I will get shown all of the treatment ID's, even the ones that did not have any active alarms.

```
let _StartTime = ago(1d);
let _EndTime = ago(0d);
let Session_Id_List = Database1
| where StartTime >= _StartTime and StartTime <= _EndTime
| summarize by SessionId, SerialNumber, StartTime
| distinct SessionId, StartTime, SerialNumber;
let treatment_alarms1 = Database1
| where StartTime >= _StartTime and StartTime <= _EndTime and TranslatedData_Status == "ALARM_ACTIVE" 
| summarize number_alarms = count() by TranslatedData_Value, SessionId 
| project final_Value = strcat(number_alarms, "x ", TranslatedData_Value), SessionId;
let treatment_alarms2 = Database1
| where StartTime >= _StartTime and StartTime <= _EndTime and TranslatedData_Status == "ALARM_ACTIVE" 
| join kind=inner treatment_alarms1 on SessionId
| summarize list_of_alarms_all = make_set(final_Value) by SessionId
| project SessionId,  list_of_alarms_all;
let final_join = Session_Id_List
| join kind=leftouter treatment_alarms2 on SessionId;
final_join
| project SessionId, list_of_alarms_all
```

Then I put this query into Excel, by using the following method

1. I go to Tools -> Query to Power BI on Kusto Explorer

[image]

2. I go to Data -> Get Data -> From Other Sources -> Blank Query

[image]

3. I go to advanced editor

[image]

4. I copy and paste my query and press "Done" at the bottom

[image]

5. If you see now, the preview of my data will show "List" on the list_of_alarms_all column, rather than showing me the actual values of the list.

[image]

6. To fix this issue I first press the arrows on the header of the column

[image]

7. I press on "Extract Values"

[image]

8. I select Custom -> Concatenate using special characters -> Line Feed -> Press OK

[image]

9. That works fine for all of the ID's that do have alarms on them, it shows them as a list and tells me how many there are, the issue is with the ID's that did not have any treatments where I get "Error" on the Excel preview. Once I press "Close & Load" the data is put on the worksheet and it looks fine, the "Error" are all gone and instead I get empty cells where the "Error" would be at.

[image]

The problem now starts when I close the file and try to open it again.

First I get this message. So I press yes to try and enter the file.

[image]

Then I get this other message. The problem with this message is that it says that I have the file open when that is not true. I even tried to restart my laptop and open the file again and I would still get the message when in reality I don't have that file open.

[image]

Then I get this message, telling me that the connection to the query was removed.

[image]

So my problem here is that 1) I can't edit the file anymore unless I make a copy because I keep getting the message saying that I already have the file opened and it is locked for editing and 2) I would like to refresh this query with VBA maybe once a week from now on but I can't because when I save the file the connection to the query is deleted by excel itself.

I'm not sure of why this is happening, I'm guessing it's because of the "Error" I get on the empty cells when I try to extract the values from the lists. If anybody has any information on how I can fix this so I don't get these error messages please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your issue, however there are some things you might want to try.

1. Within ADX, you could wrap you query with a function, so you won't have to copy a large piece of code into your Excel.
2. You could deal with null values (this is what gives you the `Error` values) already in your query. Note the use of `coalesce`.

```
// I used datatable to mimic your query results

.create-or-alter function SessionAlarms()
{
    datatable (SessionId:int,list_of_alarms_all:dynamic)
    [
         1, dynamic([10,20,30])
        ,2, dynamic([])
        ,3, dynamic(null)
    ]
    | extend list_of_alarms_all = coalesce(list_of_alarms_all, dynamic([]))
}
```

3. You can use Power Query ADX connector and copy your query/function As Is

[image: From Azure Data Explorer]

[image: eAzure Data Explorer (Kusto)]

4. If you haven't dealt with null values in you KQL you can take care of the error in Excel by using `Replace Errors`

[image: Replace Errors]

Comment: it worked by adding the extend list_of_alarms_all = coalesce(list_of_alarms_all, dynamic([])) the original file still has the "locked for editing" error but the copy seems to work and I can open and close it without having any issues.